# laravel append value in certain property

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a collection Pages

```
$pages = Pages::select('image')->where('chapter_id',$chapter_id)->get();
```

it returns

```
"data": [
  {
    "image": "01.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "03.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "04.jpg"
  }]
```

how to add value (a url path) in image property, so in my case i want it to return like this :

```
"data": [
  {
    "image": "https://example.com/01.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "https://example.com/02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "https://example.com/03.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "https://example.com/04.jpg"
  },]
```

thank you

Comment: That is an array which returns an object, Do you want to append the url to it in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to to create an accessor on your Page Model. 
On your Page model, add a method like this below;

```
public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    return "https://example.com".$value; //this will be a default rendering anytime your image field is called from your db
}
```

Comment: @BetoSiahaan Side note: If `example.com` is your Laravel app's domain, using `return url($value)` or `return asset($value)` will save you a lot of grief for local development or if you ever change your URL.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to `do not create accessor` on the same name as the column name because you cannot get its original value outside of the model ever after.

**use a separate name for accessor instead**.

```
public function getImageFullUrlAttribute(){  //or any name you want
 return ...       
}
```

Then you call this function by removing `get` and `Attribute` words in above example, the function name will be `imageFullUrl()`
You can call it then `$image->imageFullUrl()`

**Moreover:**

you can also append it on each response using `$appends` property of model class.

```
$appends = ['image_full_url'];  
// this is snake_case name of above function excluding get and Attribute words
```

Now you can call it using `$image->image_full_url`

But be careful while using `$appends` because it can eagerload if you use a relationship in  it which will slow down the response time to dead slow.

My suggestion is to only use `$appends` on columns and do not use any relationship in it.